# How to sequentially fill a 3d matrix in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an nd-array 'A' of dimensions (n, m, p), and I have a list of length n*m that contains arrays a1,a2,.. each of the arrays being of length p. What I am trying to do is to sequentially (by rows) fill 'A' using the arrays 'a'. Consider for instance the following example:

```
A = np.empty ((2,3,4))

a1 = np.array([1,2,3,0])
a2 = np.array([3,4,6,9])
a3 = np.array([9,5,8,5])
a4 = np.array([1,5,4,2])
a5 = np.array([9,7,0,5])
a6 = np.array([4,3,2,1])
lst = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6]
```

I am trying to find some way to do

```
A = DoSomething(A, lst)
print(A)
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  6.,  9.],
        [ 9.,  5.,  8.,  5.]],
       [[ 1.,  5.,  4.,  2.],
        [ 9.,  7.,  0.,  5.],
        [ 4.,  3.,  2.,  1.]]])
```

So this way `A[0, 0, :]=a1, A[0, 1, :]=a2` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
>>> A.reshape(len(lst), -1)[...] = lst
>>> A
array([[[1., 2., 3., 0.],
        [3., 4., 6., 9.],
        [9., 5., 8., 5.]],

       [[1., 5., 4., 2.],
        [9., 7., 0., 5.],
        [4., 3., 2., 1.]]])
```

A few timings for an upscaled example:

```
>>> A = np.empty ((2000,300,40))
>>> lst = 100000*[l.repeat(10) for l in lst]
>>> 
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=5)
>>> 
# my solution: fast, short, readable
>>> timeit("A.reshape(len(lst), -1)[...] = lst", **kwds)
0.8862412960734218
# @hpaulj's suggestion slow, very short, very readable
>>> timeit("A.flat[:] = lst", **kwds)
1.7412563359830528
# @FHTMitchell 1 fast, long, index-heavy
>>> timeit("for index in range(A.shape[0]): A[index] = lst[A.shape[1]*index : A.shape[1]*(index + 1)]", **kwds)0.8682223120704293
# @FHTMitchell 2 middling, short, very readable
>>> timeit("np.array(lst).reshape(A.shape)", **kwds)
1.0178500059992075
# @anishtain4 slow, short, misleading
>>> timeit("np.c_[lst].reshape(A.shape)", **kwds)
2.458487769123167
```

Comment: more succinctly: `A.flat[:]=lst`

Comment: @hpaulj Cool, I totally wasn't aware of that. How does it work? It doesn't seem equivalent, much faster for small arrays, much slower for large ones.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do

```
A[0] = lst[:3]
A[1] = lst[3:]
```

programatically, I guess this is done

```
for index in range(A.shape[0]):
     A[index] = lst[A.shape[1]*index : A.shape[1]*(index + 1)]
```

---

Alternatively just do

```
A = np.array(lst, dtype=float).reshape((2, 3, 4))
```

output:

```
[[[1. 2. 3. 0.]
  [3. 4. 6. 9.]
  [9. 5. 8. 5.]]

 [[1. 5. 4. 2.]
  [9. 7. 0. 5.]
  [4. 3. 2. 1.]]]
```

Comment: `np.array`, `np.vstack`, `np,stack`, `np.c_` etc are all perfectly good ways of combining these 6 arrays into one `(6,4)` array.  The concatenation family of functions all take a list of arrays, which is exactly what `lst` is.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a pythonic way:

```
A=np.c_[lst].reshape((2,3,4))
```

This doesn't need the initialisation of the the array `A`.

I won't include other solutions as having loops is just redundant code and for larger arrays is much slower.

Comment: I can understand not wanting to use reshape, it is a bit hacky. Also, the canonical way to initialise arrays is `np.array` and `np.asarray`, not `np.c_` and `np.r_`.

Comment: @FHTMitchell I don't see how it can be hacky if you know your shape. Here `np.array` does the same thing, but it does not give control over the shape, Can you give a reference on who has decided it's the canonical way? Last time I checked they're not deprecated. Also not cool editing your answer to include another answer

Comment: I, too, can't find fault with `reshape`. But I can with `c_` in this context, because here it amounts to one very obfuscated and slow call to `array`. It does _not_ do any stacking of its own. It would if `lst` were a tuple, but then it would stack the wrong way.

Comment: @anishtain4 I edited my answer before you had even posted yours... They are not deprecated, but very little is in the numpy ecosystem. However, [`np.c_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) is explicitly for concatenating arrays along the last axis, not for initialisation.